# Textbox convert letters to number

Tags: c#

The problem is I can not type letters like a in textbox. It doesnt convert letters like, a,b to number so it doesnt work what function can I use? Check the code:

```
try
{                
    if (Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text) == 100)
        MessageBox.Show("Activated");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("License key is not valid.", "License key is not valid.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
}
catch (System.FormatException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The problem is I can not type letters like a in textbox.

Comment: [Int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You already converted it so what is the problem?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question..

Comment: Your "license key" is laughably easy to bypass as well.

Comment: So...what is the issue/problem?

Comment: do you want to convert hex string to int?  int.Parse("10026AB0", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

Answer (score 1):

If you want to parse hex numbers, specify Number style, for example:

```
int.Parse("10026AB0", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
```

or

```
bool valid = Int32.TryParse("10026AB0", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier,null, out var number1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Int32.TryParse(string s, out int result); instead of just converting.
The bool returned will show you if the conversion was successfull.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2

```
int number1, number2, number3, number4;

if (Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out number1) && Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out number2) &&
    Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out number3) && Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out number4))
{
    if(number1 + number2 + number3 + number4 == 100)
        MessageBox.Show("Activated");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("License key is not valid.", "License key is not valid.", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
}
else
    MessageBox.Show("No letters allowed in the textboxes.", "No letters allowed in the textboxes", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);
```

Comment: When I press the button when there is a and numbers it doesnt do anything. When I press button when there is just numbers it works...